# WHERE statement conditional

Tags: mysql

I am not sure what to write, must be simple but can't figure it out.
I have a sql request I want to do.

simple request:

```
SELECT name FROM #table WHERE id=$id AND  phone='$phone'
```

Let say I do not provide the $phone variable or is empty, can I remove all the AND phone='$phone' from the select statement. so it would be

```
SELECT name FROM #table WHERE id=$id
```

Comment: I really hope you're [properly escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) those variables. Seeing things like `$phone` in a query is usually a sign something is very, very wrong.

Comment: Can you trust the source of these parameters? Could it conceivably be malicious persons? If so you need to sandbox and scrub the raw data.

Comment: In that case you should build the WHERE clause at run time in conditional statements and concatenate it on. Though you will probably get away with this, I would feel negligent if I did not say that this is a point of vulnerability in these systems. Google sql-injection-attack. There are several techniques used to improve security that you do not show and I don't have space for. Please choose one or better some and use them!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're building this query, so just build it dynamically. The basic logic would be:

```
if ($phone == '') {
   $sql = "SELECT name ... WHERE id=$id"
} else {
   $sql = "SELECT name ... WHERE id=$id AND phone='$phone'";
}
```

Comment: The SQL sttement is written by a application, I cant tell the application tu use a different $sql.  Other wise I have to create a $sql for each possibility.  That is why if I can do it with just SQL and not php coding before it would be better

Comment: then, no, you can't really do this. @Dan Andrews solution below would KIND of work, but it'd only fine records where the phone field matches, or is empty. you proably want to get ALL phones, regardless of value, if $phone is empty.

Comment: @MarcB I think your right.  The requirement to see all phones regardless of the ID wasn't clearly defined in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
SELECT name FROM #table WHERE id=$id AND (phone='$phone' or '$phone' = '')
```

Are you troubleshooting performance due to an index on [phone]?

Comment: Smooth and simple. I like that. BTW Joe Frambach, can you trust the source of these parameters not to be malicious?

Comment: No.  the real SELECt statement is much more complicated.  Basically, I am doing a report, by date range, for a specific group of people.  THe report needs to be available for each user or a summary of everyone.  I have created the summary SLEECT statement, but I do not include the salesman in the request.  If I want to have the same report, but for each salesman, I want to have a AND salesman = $id in the WHERE clause.  Same report, but if salesman is present from the form request sent before, than it show, otherwise it is not present

Comment: Did you try my method? `(salesman = $id or '$id' = '')` Using this method will allow you to make a PROC out of it and cached the compiled code. Adhoc queries will have to be compiled each time. The question really is if there will be too much of a performance hit on having the column in your where clause AND does readability matter?

Comment: Ok, I was hoping I could do something like this:  SELECT NAME, FROM #table WHERE id=$id IF($phone =='123', AND phone = $phone, '')

Comment: See @A.O.'s solution to build the where clause dynamically (not to be confused with dynamic SQL)

Comment: could i dynamically do this:  WHERE ... AND IF(phone == $phone, phone = $phone, phone <> '')

Comment: In that case you should build the WHERE clause at run time in conditional statements and concatenate it on. Though you will probably get away with this, I would feel negligent if I did not say that this is a point of vulnerability in these systems. Google sql-injection-attack. There are several techniques used to improve security that you do not show and I don't have space for. Please choose one or better some and use them!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM #table WHERE id=$id";

if(isset($phone)){
    $query .= " AND phone = '$phone'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the the `$phone` variable is set first.

I'm also assuming here that your phone variable is supposed to be an integer.

```
if($phone AND isset($phone)) {
   $phone = intval($phone);
   if($phone) {
       // sql query with the phone variable
   } else {
       // sql query without the phone variable
   }
}
```